# Should I list Design Patterns on my resume?

Tags: software-industry, resume, skills

I'm rewriting my resume, and am trying to figure out if I should include design patterns in the "Summary of Skills" section.

Is it recommended to include major design patterns on my resume? Or does this just contribute to the [tldr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aToo_long;_didn%27t_read) factor, and I should just let design patterns come up in the interview?

The design patterns I am considering adding are MVC and MVVM, and they directly relate to the sort of jobs I want to apply for (ASP.Net or WPF/Silverlight development).

Comment: I list them on my resume because I feel that they are vital skills that are important to my line of work.

Comment: Design patterns are nomenclature for commonly-occurring solutions to problems.  I wouldn't call recognizing them a skill any more than being able to tell an `while` loop from a `for` loop.

Comment: @Blrfl - Recognizing them is irrelavent.  Being able to implement the patterns in software is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To me a Design Pattern is something like Singleton or Strategy and that's way too small to go on a resume. MVC and MVVM are closer to frameworks, and you should definitely list them. Most resumes I see have a Technologies section that is just a list of languages, frameworks, tools and the like, something like:

> C#, ASP.NET MVC, SQL, Windows Forms, WPF, XAML, MVVM, Visual Studio, Git, TFS, Scrum, Python, Ruby

I do pay attention to that list - if I want to hire a Windows 8 C++ developer then a C# dev who knows XAML and MVVM is still eligible for consideration, but a C# developer who's been doing exclusively web things will need to show me a reason I should believe they can do client development.

Don't get worked up about whether something is a language or not, is a framework or not, since half the people reading your resume are screening for buzzwords and don't know what any of them mean. The 6 extra characters it takes to add `, MVVM` to your resume could be the difference for getting the interview.

Answer (score 12):

In general I would add "Design patterns" as a single entry in the skills section. That's worth doing because it draws attention to the fact that you know what a design pattern is and that its important. Don't list individual patterns like Singleton or Visitor. That's far too detailed and looks like you are trying to pad your resume.

MVC and/or MVVM might be the only exceptions to that - however only do that if you think they are explicitly relevant to the job you are applying for, and you haven't listed other experience where they would be considered normal. So if using MVC would be normal in ASP.Net programming, and you have ASP.Net experience, don't bother listing them too.

It also depends how long your resume is. If its short, adding a couple of things won't hurt. If it's long then those are the things you should cut.

Comment: Thank you, your answer was useful to me however I am accepting [Kate's answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/11952/316) because her point of *"The 6 extra characters it takes to add `, MVVM` to your resume could be the difference for getting the interview."* really struck home for me.

Answer (score 4):

Depends. If you are junior to mid, it is worthwhile putting such things. But if you are senior or above, it will sound a little cheesy.

The reason I say cheesy is because if you are a decent senior developer worth his or her salt, you should be using design patterns anyways. That's an integral part of Object Oriented Development